# Posts page loads blank

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, parse-error

Just learning to code, I am a graphic designer. I've come across an issue on a client's site. Posts pages are showing up blank. I realize there is an issue the .php. I finally was able to get this message to load to one of the posts:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /nfs/c05/h03/mnt/76600/domains/internationalsnps.org/html/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/single.php
>   on line 82

I located the code line here:

```
  <?php the_tags(__('Tagged with:', 'responsive') . ' ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like some errors https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the wp-config.php file and change debug into true from false. Then it will show you the true error.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the template 'single.php.'
Go into one of these pages that isn't working in the admin section of wordpress and change the template to anything else. Your page will then show.